# Ошибка в коде "отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора"

Tags: c++

делая программу с наследниками столкнулся со следующей ошибкой: отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "имя_конструктора::имя_конструктора", соответствующие списку аргументов. Прошу не кидайте камнями, с C++ начал знакомство только недавно (примерно месяц). Прикрепляю скрины главного модуля (main.cpp), базового класса (Good.cpp и Good.h) и класса наследника (food.cpp и food.h).
Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите в чем дело!

main.cpp:

```
#include "C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\lab4\lab4\clothes.h"
#include "C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\lab4\lab4\Good.h"
#include "C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\lab4\lab4\food.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    food f1("Lays", 95, "Crisps");
}
```

good.h:

```
#ifndef GOOD_H
#define GOOD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Good
{
public:
    Good();
    int getPrice();
    virtual void show();
    void setManuf(char*);
    void setPrice(int);
protected:
    char manuf[20];
    int price;
private:
};
#endif // GOOD_H
```

good.cpp:

```
#include "C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\lab4\lab4\Good.h"

using namespace std;

Good::Good():price(0) {
    strcpy(manuf, "NoManufacturer");
}
int Good::getPrice() {
    return price;
}
void Good::show() {
    cout << "Manufacturer: " << manuf << " Price: " << price << endl;
}
void Good::setManuf(char* mf) {
    strcpy(manuf, mf);
}
void Good::setPrice(int pr) {
    price = pr;
}
```

food.h:

```
#ifndef FOOD_H
#define FOOD_H

#include "Good.h"

class food : public Good
{
    public:
        food(char*, int, char*);
        void setKindof(char*);
        void show();
    protected:
    private:
        char kindof[15];
};
#endif // FOOD_H
```

food.cpp:

```
#include "C:\Users\HOME\source\repos\lab4\lab4\food.h"


food::food(char* mf, int pr, char* kf) {
    strcpy(manuf, mf);
    price = pr;
    strcpy(kindof, kf); 
}
void food::setKindof(char* kf) {
    strcpy(kindof, kf);
}
void food::show() {
    cout << "Manufacturer: " << manuf << " Price: " << price << " Kind of food: " << kindof << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Код здесь дают в виде текста, а не скриншотами. Не понимаю, кстати - неужели скриншоты делать проще, чем Ctrl-C Ctrl-V нажать? :)

Comment: Извините, только зарегистрировался, не знал как тут код нужно вставлять

Comment: Тем, кто отвечает часто нужно воспроизводить и модифицировать ваш код. Заставлять их все это перепечатывать - преступление. Более того, через время  хостинг картинок может снести все старые картинки и от Вашего вопроса не будет совершенно никакой пользы, для других пользователей. К тому же код индексируют поисковые системы, что помогает другим пользователям находить ответы с такими же проблемами, что в случае с картинками сделать невозможно

Comment: Я понял Вас, все исправил.

Comment: `"Lays"`  это литерал. На  него и другие строковые литералы может указать только константный указатель, а в конструкторе у вас аргументы не const char*. Исправьте на   `food( const char*, int, const char*)`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan сделал как Вы сказали, вроде помогло, спасибо большое!!!